# WhatsApp Desktop - broadcast lists not showing after recent update

Tags: whatsapp

I recently updated WhatsApp Desktop to the latest version and all of a sudden my broadcast lists are not showing on the desktop version anymore. This used to work just fine before the latest update.

Unfortunately, I don't know what the previous version was, but the current version that I am now running is Version 2.2149.4 on Windows 10 Home 21H1.

Has anybody encountered the same problem?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Does anyone know how to rollback to the whatsapp desktop that has broadcast lists?

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast feature is **not** available on the Windows App. The [official documentation](https://faq.whatsapp.com/861663048350950/?cms_platform=android) is shy to say that explicitly, but it describes this feature for Android and iOS only.

This other [documentation page](https://faq.whatsapp.com/378279804439436) lists the features that are **not supported** on linked devices, which is the case of the Desktop app connected to your primary phone.

- Viewing live location.
- **Creating and viewing broadcast lists**.
- Adding and deleting status on linked devices.
- Interacting with businesses using WhatsApp Flows.